# Intent not picked up by singleTop Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I have an Activity that is defined to be singleTop so that only the one instance will exist.

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MyMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" 
        android:launchMode="singleTop" android:multiprocess="true">
```

I set up a Notification Intent with some data, and include it in a PendingIntent, and send it to the Notification Manager.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyMainActivity.class); 
notificationIntent.setAction(MyMainActivity.CustomInternalMessageAction);
notificationIntent.putExtra(MyMainActivity.ReceiveTestMessage, rawMessageText);

...
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
mNotificationManager.notify(number, notification);
```

If the actiivty is not running, the intent starts the activity via onCreate() as expected.

If The activity is running, but in the stopped state / not in foreground (like when clicking the home button), and the notification is clicked, my activity's onNewIntent() is called as expected.

However, if the Activity is already called when it's in the foreground, then onNewIntent() doesn't get called.

How can I set up this notificaiton so that my singleTop Activity gets sent the intent, when it's in the pause/stop state (and also still functions in the other cases I mentioned). I'm thinking there's a flag to set on my notificationIntent object, but the functions of the flags aren't really clear for the case of singleTop activities.

Comment: Is any of the other `on` something methods get called in that situation?

Comment: no, not based on my logging. onCreate(), destroy, resume, pause, onSaveInst, onRestoreInst

Comment: It seems like this is only an issue on some devices. I am working with a similar scenario, I have 1 device that works fine, and another that does not receive the new Intents. setting the `CLEAR_TOP` flag on my intent fixed it on the devices that had issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your application is composed by more than one activity, the remain activities need to be defined as `singleTop` as well if you want to receive a `onNewIntent()`call when that activity is active.

Let suppose that main activity is `A` and is defined as `singleTop` and from there you start activity `B` not defined as `singleTop`. If now you select a notification that calls your application, the application will start on activity `B` but `onNewIntent()` is not called.

You can also override this behaviour adding the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` which remove activity `B` from stack and Activity `A` will recive the call on `onNewIntent()`.

Comment: In my case, my main activity, A, is what I want to be shown by the Notification. So in the case where the notification wasn't calling onNewIntent() on my activity A, activity B was not on the stack.

Comment: adding the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP worked in my case. onNewIntent() was called.