# Notification has data from previous notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I'm setting up a Notification with some data to open up one of my activities. If the notificatio hasn't been acknowledged yet, I'm overwriting it it with since i'm calling notifiy with the same ID.

I'm seeing the notificaiton values change, however, i'm noticing that the extra value i'm putting in to the ReceiveMessage key in the putExtra call actually has stale information.
NOtificaitonManager.notify is supposed to ovewrite an existing notification with that ID, so why am I processing stale information in the Notification's Intent?

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setAction(MyActivity.CustomInternalAction);
notificationIntent.putExtra(MyActivity.ReceiveMessage, rawMessageText);

notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
//......
mNotificationManager.notify(myId, notification);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` in your call to `getActivity()`.

Comment: OK, this ended up being related to my recent SO question about notifications not signalling the activity if the notification is set to start a singleTop activity that is already in the foreground. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861051/intent-not-picked-up-by-singletop-activity/12863842#12863842